# Google Analytics: External .js file

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Just to confirm...

**file: google.js**

```
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-11510668-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
```

And then linking the file like:

```
<script src="google.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That works, right?

Comment: yeah but then i need to wait a day to see if it actually works...

Comment: I just tested this and it seems fine (see edit to my original answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add that script to your page, then if you're using FireFox w/ FireBug (or other debugger) or Chrome, you can Inspect Element to see what's been written to the page. If you see...

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...then you should be good to go!

Answer (score 3):

[My testing](http://matchu.dreamhosters.com/write.html) shows that this works.

The sample page provided runs a `document.write()` in an external script, and then also runs `document.write()` to print out yet another script tag, to make sure that that functionality works, also. I got expected output (two lines of text) on all browsers I tested, including Internet Explorer (even 6), Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.

I think they just say to do it inline because they think it's easier for newbies.

You should be fine.

Comment: Glad you finally got me to do it. Would have been upset if I ended up losing all IE traffic or something when that project went live.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a reason it wouldn't.

Have you tried it and encountered any issues?

Edit: I just tried this and inspected it in firebug, as far as I can see, the second script tag is written correctly.

This should work.

Comment: i can't tell at the moment since it takes a day for google to update stats.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need to execute that script somehow. If you simply include it then it won't be executed. If you put it inside of a wrapper function:

```
function googleCode(){
// google code goes here
}
```

then you can use jQuery and execute it when a page is fully loaded

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
           googleCode();
        });
```

Just an idea.

Comment: This will actually slow down GA. Google Analytics is designed in most cases to be run when the page loads, such as at the top level of a JavaScript file or in a <script> tag. Wrapping things in $(document).ready() delays the execution of code until the dom is completely loaded and parsed.

Comment: Its just javascript code, not in a function so it will run as soon as parsed which will be as soon as the script file downloads. So no need to call anything, its redundant. Only issue with using external scripts is a slight delay while we do another HTTP request. But you can cache the file so it should only be an issue on first load with an empty cache and even then its minimal and not worth loosing sleep over :)